# codeigniter - make a difference in the two dates with database

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-datamapper

Help me .. !!
I 'm in the final project , build a web with Framwork CodeIgniter . but I difficulty to make a difference in the control script , the examples I list dated 07.02.2015 and should regristasi before 3 days but I forgot to register so it appears the warning .. how to make

Comment: you added 07.02.2015 in database and you want to alert before 3 days (04.02.215) right ??

Comment: @DeepParekh  yes right... you can help me,

Comment: @innoSPG Try Calibration tool

Comment: Turn on ur production mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

irwan you have to run cron job for check the date daily.
By cron job run this code :

```
$current_date=date('Y-m-d');
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+3 day", $date);
$adate=date=date('Y-m-d', $date); // this is after three days's date.
```

then run the query:

```
$this->db->where('date',$adate);
$q=$this->db->get('table');
```

then do something(whatever you want like send mail or anything) if you get data from above query.
Hope you got the point :)

Comment: Nice, but how do I implement in CodeIgniter, in the manufacture of the controller, model and view ??

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE date (date1 timestamp, date2 timestamp);

INSERT INTO date VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 05:00:00');
INSERT INTO date VALUES ('2010-03-11 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO date VALUES ('2010-03-11 00:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO date VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-03-30 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO date VALUES ('2010-03-10 12:00:00', '2010-04-01 13:00:00');

SELECT date2 as d2,date1 as d1, DATEDIFF(d2, d1) AS diff FROM date;

+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| d2                  | d1                  | diff |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 2010-03-30 05:00:00 | 2010-03-11 12:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-11 12:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-11 00:00:00 |   19 |
| 2010-03-30 13:00:00 | 2010-03-10 12:00:00 |   20 |
| 2010-04-01 13:00:00 | 2010-03-10 12:00:00 |   22 |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: it's nice , but how do I implement into CodeIgniter

Comment: in codeigniter you can use $this->db->query($query),
where $query is the query to get difference of 2 dates.